# Mail app won't let me check mail from student email address

Tags: macbook-pro, mail.app, email, gmail

My mail app lets me add my student .edu account, but then, when I try to check the box that allows mail to actually receive the emails that my student account does, it says that it can't link because it's an "unknown mail server"

Just wondering what I'm supposed to do with that...

Thanks!

Comment: So it's almost a clear message. Did you set up your mail account correctly? Could you please attach some screenshots from **Mail > Preferences > Account** tab?

Answer (score 1):

Open Help in Mail and search for can't send or can't receive.

Walk through the steps to troubleshoot this.

Last resort - open Window > Connection Doctor and dig into the specific error messages for each non green light account.